# Want to navigate to first page on a button click

Tags: reactjs, antd

In my table component my pagination options are like this :

```
 <Table scroll={{ y: records.length>50?'calc(100vh - 175px)':'calc(100vh - 130px)' }}
            pagination={{hideOnSinglePage:true,defaultPageSize:50,pageSizeOptions:['50','100','500'], showTotal:(total,range) => `${range[0]} to ${range[1]} of ${total} groups`}}
            columns={columns} 
            dataSource={records} />
```

If I go to second page or other,
[image]

from there I click a button(for example: add) I want to go back to the first page. How is it possible?

Comment: did you try to manipulate the onChange?

Comment: But how?? onChange of add click we want to set the value. What value and which variable is to set on that on change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to make it a [controlled pagination](https://ant.design/components/pagination/#components-pagination-demo-controlled)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentPage: 1
  };

  handleChange = (page) => {
    this.setState({
      currentPage: page
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
          {/* back to page one when clicked */}
          <Button type="primary" onClick={() => this.handleChange(1)}>
            Add
          </Button>
        </div>
        <Table
          columns={columns}
          dataSource={data}
          pagination={{
            current: this.state.currentPage, //newly added
            onChange: this.handleChange, //newly added
            hideOnSinglePage: true,
            defaultPageSize: 50,
            pageSizeOptions: ["50", "100", "500"],
            showTotal: (total, range) =>
              `${range[0]} to ${range[1]} of ${total} groups`,
            position: ["topRight", "bottomRight"]
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

See working sample here:

[image: Edit]

Comment: How can I do the same logic without React hooks?

Comment: I updated my answer to a class based component as well as the provided link. I also did not remove the react hooks version so you can compare it.